# Is it possible to "patch" a .exe for copy protection?

Tags: c#, c++, exe, drm, copy-protection

Is it possible to create an app in C++ or C# so I can patch a exe file for copy protection purposes?
So if a user has an account on my website with the software tied to it, I can require them to enter a key which is checked with the database and then execute or show an error.

When I say "patch", I mean applying to an already built/compiled exe. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Do you want to adjust permissions, so user could only change a file, if he logged in as superuser?

Comment: Possible, but a wholly different proposition for C# than for C++. And a bad idea in all cases.

Comment: @David - Heffernan Ah, good. Can you point me in the right direction? What should I be searching for? :)

Comment: @Henk Holterman - Oh. Why is it a bad idea? Not guaranteed to work or something?

Comment: Those types of copy protections are usually called "envelopes" (such as HASP envelope). You can search for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easily possible, many packers and protection systems like [Themida](http://www.oreans.com/themida.php) do this, however, things like this can be easily cracked, thus you need to evaluate the effort vs reward required for someone to hack your program.

However, to directly answer your question, your best bet is to hook the code entry point defined in the PE and have it redirect to your checker (OS dependant). [UPX](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=hg&group_id=2331) is an opensource executable packer, and should provide a good base to use or point of reference asa it hooks the entry of the executable to run the unpacking engine. You can also find a few articles on packers and protectors [here](http://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.90).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complicated your copy protection is, "patching" may be in the simplest case just boiled down to writing a few bytes at selected offsets in the protected EXE file.  [This project](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette) may be interesting.

Comment: Yep. As far as easy protection wrapper can be applied as easy this patching can be removed. That protection can be removed by some 'common' crack for all the products. Its a big drawback for all wrappers.